# Python importing modules that all import another module that is the same

Tags: python

What i want to is, I have foo.py it imports classes from bar1, bar2, and they both need bar3, e.g.

foo.py

```
from src import *
...
```

src/ __ init__.py

```
from bar1 import specialSandwichMaker
from bar2 import specialMuffinMaker
```

src/bar1.py

```
import bar3
class specialSandwichMaker(bar3.sandwichMaker)
...
```

src/bar2.py

```
import bar3
class specialMuffinMaker(bar3.muffinMaker)
...
```

is there a more efficient way to make bar3 available to the bar1 and bar2 files without having them directly import it?

Comment: An exception to the `from foo import *` rule that you are justifiably catching flack about is if every item in `foo` ends or begins in some name that is unique to `foo`. for example, define an `exceptions` module and have every exception end in Error. Then you can just do `from exceptions import *` and have all of your exceptions ready to `raise` or `except`. realize though that if you reload the module, the classes that are imported in this way will __not__ be reloaded with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fully efficient; when importing a module Python will add it to `sys.modules`. `import` statements first check this dictionary (which is fast because dictionary lookups are fast) to see whether the module has been imported already. So in this case, `bar1` will import `bar3` and add it to `sys.modules`. Then `bar2` will use the `bar3` that has already been imported.

You can verify this with:

```
import sys
print( sys.modules )
```

Note that `from src import *` is bad code and you shouldn't use it. Either `import src` and use `src.specialSandwichMaker` references, or `from src import specialSandwichMaker`. This is because modules shouldn't pollute each other's namespaces -- if you do `from src import *`, all the global variables defined in `src` will appear in your namespace too. This is Bad.

Comment: thanks, if i do a from src import *, does it only take globals from the __init__ file? or will it take globals from other modules within src\ ?

Comment: It's documented below. If you have defined `__all__` in `__init__.py`, it will take all of those. If you haven't, it will take only those that are explicitly imported. But this is a workaround for those people that use `import *`; you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

you should define **all** as specified in

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package